# Unable to save new Entities with One-To-Many relation in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When trying to save two new entities with a One-To-Many relation, I am getting the following error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I am using EF v6.1.3

Here is an example of the code:

```
var entity = _dbContext.Set<EntityA>().Create();

entity.Identifier = 1234;
entity.Title = "Test Title";
entity.Description = "Test Description";

_dbContext.Set<EntityA>().Add(entity);

var relatedEntity = _dbContext.Set<EntityB>().Create();

relatedEntity.Identifier = "123-1234";
relatedEntity.Title = "Test Title";
relatedEntity.Statement = "Sample Statement";
relatedEntity.Entity = entity;

_dbContext.Set<EntityB>().Add(relatedEntity);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The only way I can get this to not give the error is to call `_dbContext.SaveChanges();` before creating the related entity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is the SQL for the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EntityA]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Identifier] NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [Title] NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR (2000) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EntityB]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [Identifier] NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [Title] NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [Statement] NVARCHAR (2000) NOT NULL,
    [EntityAId] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_EntityB_EntityA] FOREIGN KEY ([EntityAId]) REFERENCES [EntityA]([Id])
)
```

Here is the `OnModelCreating` configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>()
    .HasMany(e => e.RelatedEntities)
    .WithRequired(e => e.EntityA)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.EntityAId);
```

Here are the Entity Classes:

```
[Table("EntityA")]
public class EntityA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<EntityB> RelatedEntities { get; set; }
}

[Table("EntityB")]
public class EntityB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int EntityAId { get; set; }

    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Statement { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a full [mcve], e.g. include the sample model and configuration.

Comment: @IvanStoev I have edited my question to include more information.

Comment: Cannot replicate with the provided information - EF6.1.3, SqlServer database, the above code works w/o any problem.  Looks like the exception is caused by a code not shown there.

Comment: @IvanStoev I cannot reliably re-produce it either, it seems to be random.  There are 2 ways I can get it to not produce the error 1) by adding another _dbContext.SaveChanges() and 2) by not creating/adding the related entity.

Everything I find on google seems to be related to the removal of a relation.  Can you think of any reason why I would get this error on creation?

Comment: No. The error indicates update operation. Are you reusing the `DbContext`? Try the above code with `var _dbContext = new YourDbContext();` - should never happen (at least I wasn't able to get an error on several runs).

Comment: This doesn't look like your real model (I hope). In reality, assigning a reference navigation property could "steal" it away from the original owner, possibly causing a null FK.

Answer (score 0):

The moment when you create the Entity2, Entity(1) is not yet in the database and Entity2 needs to have 1 available to create itself. You do right thing to call SaveChanges() to create Entity(1) first.

Comment: Negative. EF is capable of resolving such scenario.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I'm sure you know this better than me. Is it technically possible or also practically worth to apply such scenario? This error is quite frequent and this is quite an easy solution to avoid it, which likely for majority of scenarios should suffice?

Comment: Hi @Turo, I'm not arguing what is good or bad, just saying that the scenario is supported (it's pretty basic in order to be unsupported by self respecting ORM).